# Fill huge file with random data quickly

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, random, parallel.for

I'm trying to fill file of enormous size (>1GB) with random data.

I've written simple "thread safe random", that generates strings (solution was suggested at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/getting-random-numbers-in-a-thread-safe-way/), and reworking random to make random strings is trivial.

I'm trying to write this to file using this code:

```
String rp;

Parallel.For(1, numlines -1, i => 
{
    rp = ThreadSafeRandom.Next();
    outputFile.WriteLineAsync(rp.ToString()).Wait();
});
```

when line numbers are small file is generated perfectly.

When I enter bigger number of lines (say 30000) following happens:

- some strings are corrupted (Notepad++ sees them as prepended by lots of NUL)
- at some point i get InvalidOperationException("Thread is used by previous thread operation").

I tried making `Parallel.For(1, numlines -1, async i =>` with `await outputFile.WriteLineAsync(rp.ToString());`

and also tried doing

```cs
lock (outputFile) {
    outputFile.WriteLineAsync(rp.ToString());
}
```

I can always use single thread approach with simple for and simple writeLine() but as I've said I want to generate big files and I assume that even simple for loop that generates > 10000 records can take some time (in file with big size we will have 1e+6 or even 1e9 records, which is > then 20GB) and I can not think about any optimal approach.

Can someone suggest how to optimize this?

Comment: You cannot write to the same file with multiple threads at the same time, you need to find another approach for that

Comment: Indeed. Parallelizing IO won't buy you anything (except corruption). CPUs are much faster than the IO they manage... even single-threaded.

Comment: The #1 thing you can do to optimize writing a big file is to use `.SetLength` to grow the file first. This can be further sped up by using [`SetFileValidData`](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilevaliddata), but this requires acquiring a privilege (not particularly simple). You can use `fsutil file createnew` from an elevated command prompt separately to do the heavy lifting for this. All of this assumes you'll be OK with either a binary file or a text file with constant line sizes; writing variable-length lines in text files inherently doesn't scale.

Comment: @spender can this be sped up by parallelizing just random value generation? I thought about this approach but problem is that it would look like "generate n random strings" (in parallel) -> write them to file (not parallel). Or file writing will still be slow no matter how I try optimising data generation?

Comment: Why do you need strings at all? Converting random data to strings is likely to be the costliest of cpu/memory operations? Why not just dump random bytes to file?

Comment: @spender because in short files it's easier to check output (i intend to work with it later). And generating string of 20 symbols is same as generating just 20 symbols / bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your limiting factor is probably the speed of your hard disk. Nevertheless you may gain some performance by splitting the work in two. One thread (the producer) will produce the random lines, and another thread (the consumer) will write the produced lines in the file. The code bellow writes 1,000,000 random lines to a file in my SSD in less than a second (10 MB).

```
BlockingCollection<string> buffer = new(boundedCapacity: 10);
Task producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Random random = new();
    StringBuilder sb = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) // 10,000 chunks
    {
        sb.Clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) // 100 lines each chunk
        {
            sb.AppendLine(random.Next().ToString());
        }
        buffer.Add(sb.ToString());
    }
    buffer.CompleteAdding();
}, default, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
Task consumer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    using StreamWriter outputFile = new(@".\..\..\Huge.txt");
    foreach (string chunk in buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        outputFile.Write(chunk);
    }
}, default, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
Task.WaitAll(producer, consumer);
```

This way you don't even need thread safety in the production of the random lines, because the production happens on a single thread.

---

**Update:** In case the writing to disk is not the bottleneck, and the producer is slower than the consumer, more producers can be added. Below is a version with three producers and one consumer.

```
BlockingCollection<string> buffer = new(boundedCapacity: 10);
Task[] producers = Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
.Select(n => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Random random = new(n); // Non-random seed, same data on every run
    StringBuilder sb = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        sb.Clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(random.Next().ToString());
        }
        buffer.Add(sb.ToString());
    }
}, default, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default))
.ToArray();
Task allProducers = Task.WhenAll(producers).ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    buffer.CompleteAdding();
}, TaskScheduler.Default);
// Consumer the same as previously (omitted)
Task.WaitAll(allProducers, consumer);
```

Comment: It seems that this is good approach. Why did you set upper bounds on BlockingCollection?

buffer.Add(sb.ToString()) is for minimising writes to BlockingCollection, so consumer will immediately get big chunk? Will peformance differ if we just use buffer.add(random.Next().ToString())? I haven't worked with concurrent collections, so I'm sorry if my question seems stpid

Comment: The problem with letting the `BlockingCollection` unbounded is that the producer may be much faster than the consumer, and suddenly you'll have huge amounts of produced data in memory, risking an `OutOfMemoryException`. Also writing too small chunks of data in the `BlockingCollection` will cause too much overhead, because of the thread synchronization involved during the enumeration of the `ConsumingEnumerable`. 100 lines per chunk may not be optimal. It depends on the size of each line. Some experimentation will show you the optimal value.

Comment: Added a multi-producer example.

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark your answer as accepted. BTW, I'm pretty sure that writes will be bottleneck. It's hard to imagine case where generating random will take longer then writing it to disk.

Comment: Yes, otherwise you would have a very slow CPU or a very fast SSD. Which is probably my case because I get a 20% speed boost with 2 producers in my AMD Athlon PC!