# How to speed up a chunky BlockingCollection implementation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, blockingcollection

I have used many times the [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) for implementing the producer/consumer pattern, but I have experienced bad performance with extremely granular data because of the associated overhead. This usually forces me to improvise by chunkifying/partitioning my data, in other words using a `BlockingCollection<T[]>` instead of `BlockingCollection<T>`. Here is a [resent example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56903490/11178549). This works but it's ugly and error-prone. I end up using nested loops at both the producer and the consumer, and I must remember to `Add` what is left at the end of a producer's workload. So I had the idea of implementing a chunky `BlockingCollection`, that will handle all these complications internally, and will externalize the same simple interface with the existing `BlockingCollection`. My problem is that I haven't managed yet to match the performance of the complex manual partitioning. My best attempt still pays a performance tax of around +100%, for extremely granular data (basically just integer values). So I would like to present here what I have done so far, hoping for an advice that will help me close the performance gap.

My best attempt is using a [`ThreadLocal<List<T>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1), so that each thread works on a dedicated chunk, removing any need for locks.

```
public class ChunkyBlockingCollection1<T>
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<T[]> _blockingCollection;
    public readonly int _chunkSize;
    private readonly ThreadLocal<List<T>> _chunk;

    public ChunkyBlockingCollection1(int chunkSize)
    {
        _blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<T[]>();
        _chunkSize = chunkSize;
        _chunk = new ThreadLocal<List<T>>(() => new List<T>(chunkSize), true);
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        var chunk = _chunk.Value;
        chunk.Add(item);
        if (chunk.Count >= _chunkSize)
        {
            _blockingCollection.Add(chunk.ToArray());
            chunk.Clear();
        }
    }

    public void CompleteAdding()
    {
        var chunks = _chunk.Values.ToArray();
        foreach (var chunk in chunks)
        {
            _blockingCollection.Add(chunk.ToArray());
            chunk.Clear();
        }
        _blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetConsumingEnumerable()
    {
        foreach (var chunk in _blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < chunk.Length; i++)
            {
                yield return chunk[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My second best attempt is using a single `List<T>` as chunk, that is accessed by all threads in a thread safe manner using a lock. Surprisingly this is only slightly slower than the `ThreadLocal<List<T>>` solution.

```
public class ChunkyBlockingCollection2<T>
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<T[]> _blockingCollection;
    public readonly int _chunkSize;
    private readonly List<T> _chunk;
    private readonly object _locker = new object();

    public ChunkyBlockingCollection2(int chunkSize)
    {
        _blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<T[]>();
        _chunkSize = chunkSize;
        _chunk = new List<T>(chunkSize);
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            _chunk.Add(item);
            if (_chunk.Count >= _chunkSize)
            {
                _blockingCollection.Add(_chunk.ToArray());
                _chunk.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public void CompleteAdding()
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            _blockingCollection.Add(_chunk.ToArray());
            _chunk.Clear();
        }
        _blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetConsumingEnumerable()
    {
        foreach (var chunk in _blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < chunk.Length; i++)
            {
                yield return chunk[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to use as chunk a `ConcurrentBag<T>`, which resulted in bad performance and an issue with correctness (because I didn't use a lock). Another attempt was replacing the `lock (_locker)` with a [`SpinLock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.spinlock), with even worse performance. The locking is clearly the root of my problems, because if I remove it completely then my class obtains optimal performance. Of course removing the lock fails miserably with more than one producers.

Comment: Starting title with *I need ideas* will attract the wrong type of attention.

Comment: @Nkosi it seems that my question attracted no attention nonetheless.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, Did you try to use `BlockingCollection<T>[]` ?

Comment: @DmitryStepanov no I haven't. How would this work?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, have a look at this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-use-arrays-of-blockingcollections)

Comment: @DmitryStepanov the example in Microsoft's article is quite complex. I am not sure that using multiple `BlockingCollection`s will help me improve the performance of my implementation. Currently the throughput of the `ChunkyBlockingCollection1` class is around 10,000,000 items per second, using chunks of 200 items each (in a setup of 1 producer and 1 consumer). Doing the chunking manually beats my class by doing the same in less than half a second. The focus of my implementation is on extremely granular data, where there is barely any processing at all for each item.

Comment: First, I'd suggest reading http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Concurrent_Collections and the section below that, and then see if you can find a way to tell if your threads are doing something most of the time, or if they're spending a lot of time blocking, or what.  If they're mostly waiting on the producer, then you have a different problem if the queue is filling, and the producer is waiting for the consumers, or if it's pure lock/block overhead.  10,000,000/s is outside of what a lot of "normal wisdom" deals with, so be careful.

Comment: Hi @KevinAnderson, I have read Joseph'a book quite recently. It was a good reading! My two attempts have different characteristics. `ChunkyBlockingCollection1` doesn't use locks, so there is no contention and scales excellently, at the cost of not being completely thread safe. It relies on callers for thread safety. `ChunkyBlockingCollection2` uses a shared chunk and locks on `Add` and `CompleteAdding`, so it is 100% thread safe, at the cost of having a lot of contention when the producers are more than one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with an array for `_chunk` instead of using `List<T>`.  Then, you can use Interlocked.Increment to increment the next index to populate on `Add` and when your count exceeds the size of your chunk, move it all to the blocking collection and reset the index in a lock, of course.

Comment: It would be very nice if I could get rid of the `lock` in the `Add` method, but I don't think it is possible. Without `lock` I risk pushing an array in the `BlockinCollection` before all its elements are filled with data. Resulting in a `NullReferenceException` when processed by the consumer thread.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, you have a point. To eliminate the race-condition, if Interlocked.Increment returns a value that exceeds the size of the chunk, then you can spin-wait (using Increment.CompareExchange) to wait until the operation to move the chunk to the BlockingCollection and then reset the current index for the chunk completes.

Comment: This is worth a try!