# How to wait on AutoResetEvent and be able to terminate the wait after cancel is called?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I need to be able to wait for an event, but also be able to terminate the wait after cancel is called.

I use `AutoResetEvent` as a way to wait on a signal to continue the work. To be able to cancel the wait, I came up with two solutions:

1. Register a delegate with `CancellationToken.Register` that will set `AutoResetEvent`.
2. Using `TaskCompletionSource`. But, since I cannot reuse `TaskCompletionSource`, I came up with the solution to queue new `TaskCompletionSource` each time a new event is fired.

Are these proper solutions or there are more elegant ways to do this?

**Solution 1**

```
class MyClass
{
   AutoResetEvent _dataArrivedSignal = new AutoResetEvent (false);
   public Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
       return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
          cancellationToken.Register(() => _dataArrivedSignal.Set());

          while(condition)
          {
              DoSomeWork();
              
              _dataArrivedSignal.WaitOne();

              cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
          }
       }
   }

   private void OnDataArrived(EventArgs args)
   {
       _dataArrivedSignal.Set();
   }
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
class MyClass
{
   ConcurrentQueue<TaskCompletionSource> _awaiters = new ConcurrentQueue<TaskCompletionSource>();
   TaskCompletionSource _waiter;

   public MyClass3()
   { 
       _waiter = new TaskCompletionSource();
       _awaiters.Enqueue(_waiter);
   }

   public Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
       return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
          while(condition)
          {
              DoSomeWork();
              
              _awaiters.TryDequeue(out TaskCompletionSource waiter);
              waiter.Task.Wait(cancellationToken);

              cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
          }
       }
   }

   private void OnDataArrived(EventArgs args)
   {
        var newWaiter = new TaskCompletionSource();
        _awaiters.Enqueue(newWaiter);

        _waiter.SetResult();
        _waiter = newWaiter;
   }
}
```

Comment: *`while(condition)`* -- What is the `condition`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, the `condition` is `dataArrivedCount == _total`

Comment: Have you considered using a higher level tool, like the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) or the [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) or the TPL Dataflow library, instead of the primitive `ConcurrentQueue<T>`+`TaskCompletionSource`+`AutoResetEvent`?

Comment: Can you give an example what you mean?

Comment: An example of using a `BlockingCollection<T>` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902688/fill-huge-file-with-random-data-quickly/56903490#56903490). I don't know if the example is relevant with what you are trying to do.

Comment: I know what `BlockingCollection<T>` is?:) I didn't understand how you want to use it for what I want to do it. Anyway...

Comment: It just looks like you have producer-consumer queue (one end adds data to process, the other end consumes the data). If that's so then indeed BlockingCollection backed by ConcurrentQueue might be suitable. Then your code will just consume items from that queue in a loop and that's it (it will block until more data is available).

Comment: @Evk, the `DoSomeWork` sends async data out via third-party service. When the data got processed the acknowledgement of how many have been processed is sent back via event. Then, another chunk of data is sent.
I'll reconsider using `BlockingCollection`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is more elegant way. Note that `AutoResetEvent` inherits from `WaitHandle`. `CancellationToken` in turn has property `WaitHandle`, described as:

> Gets a WaitHandle that is signaled when the token is canceled.

Then, `WaitHandle` has static method `WaitAny` which accepts array of wait handles and returns an index in that array of first wait handle that was signaled.

So to achieve what you want - use:

```
public Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        while (condition) {
            DoSomeWork();
            int signaled = WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { _dataArrivedSignal, cancellationToken.WaitHandle });
            if (signaled == 0) {
                // your _dataArrivedSignal was signaled
            }
            else {
                // cancellation token was signaled
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`WaitAny` can also accept timeout in case you actually use `WaitOne` with timeout in real code.